# Where to ask technical problems/bugs about video games

Tags: support, site-recommendation

As the title says, is there a SE site which lets people ask about technical bugs / problems about video games? Made-up example, I found a bug where you can die randomly while flying in Minecraft.

Comment: You mean you've *found* a bug, and would like to ask what, exactly? Or are you working on a video game and you need to fix a bug? Could you supply an example?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ sounds fitting, there are also questions about technical issues e.g. wrong card, OS issues etc.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen, Yes, to ask if there's any workaround or hack to **fix** the bug. What other technical questions would you want to ask about bugs besides that?

Comment: @Pacerier "Help, I was playing *[popular video game franchise]* and it's freezing every time I try to move to the next level! Does anyone know of a way to get around that?" versus "Help, I'm writing a video game and *[this keeps happening]*! Here's my code, what's wrong with it?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Shadow Wizard said in a comment above, [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) does sometimes deal with this sort of thing ("Game-specific hardware and utilities" is the most relevant on-topic listing there).

But in general, I'm not sure what you're describing is really appropriate for the Stack Exchange network. It really just depends on what you're hoping to find out.

If you post the "question," "hey guys! I found a bug! Isn't this awesome?" you probably won't be well-received, and the very best-case answer will be something along the lines of "yep! I'm reproing that, too." If you're certain that what you've found is actually a bug in the software, your best bet would be to go to the manufacturer and report it via whatever means they have set up, if any.

On the other hand, if your question is more along the lines of "*[this weird thing]* is happening under *[these specifically laid out circumstances]*, is this a bug? And is there a known work-around if so?" that's probably more suitable. Of course, that could also be prone to a self-answer, if you find a bug and want to post your solution.

But, just like with Stack Overflow, remember that sites in the Stack Exchange network aren't a direct link to developers of specific software, and consequently shouldn't be used for bug reporting (except for [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s about Stack Exchange itself) or other customer service requests. Arqade is probably your best bet, but just make sure that you're actually asking a *question* when you go there.

It might not be a bad idea to hop on their chat and see whether people think it would be a good thing to post on the main site. I'm not immediately familiar with their practical scope, and anyone there probably will be. They might also be able to help you assess whether it's reproducible, which could be good to know going into asking your question.